# Creating sub sections (groups) of layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, group-layer

I am working on a project regarding Fish species and fishing methods with many layers.

This creates confusion.

I would like to create layer sub sections (groups) like the following:

- Fish Species

  - species 1
  - species 2
  - species 3
- Fishing Methods

  - method 1
  - method 2
  - method 3

and so on.

Possibly even a 2nd level sub section (layer group).

I have no idea how to tackle this.

I'm using QGIS 2.4.

To clarify an image of the project is below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another option:  Select multiple layers (using either Shift-click to select a group or Ctrl click to individually add layers to your selection).  When you have several selected, right-click and choose "Group Selected".  I find this less fiddly than first creating the group and then dragging layers to it (although that is a perfectly valid option).

Answer (score 5):

If you right-click in the Layer's window, there should be an **Add group** option. Select this to create sub-sections by dragging your layers into it.

Comment: This works only when you click underneath the layers, as long as there is free space left. In QGIS 2.6, there is a new icon bar above the layers window, which makes it easier if the window is completely filled with layers.

Comment: Cheers for making this clear.